# Track HTTP requests of an application

Tags: android

I am creating an application which has to track http requests made by a given application. Android has many widgets like weather report widget, stock market report etc, which often makes request to server to get the data. I want all the request url made by an appklication to the server.

Can we log the url when an application accesses network/wifi or any other data service provider ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Get a wifi access point with logging?

Comment: Only the url which makes request from my application to any network service - wifi / GPRS ...

Answer (score 3):

> Can we log the url when an application accesses network/wifi or any other data service provider ?

Fortunately, no, for obvious privacy and security reasons. Malware authors would be very interested in this capability.

Comment: Makes sense. What if, I have complete control over the aplication. Say for example, I have developed an application, which makes request to the servers. Can I make any changes in that, so that I can get the URL, everytime it hits the server through NETWORK-ACCESS

Comment: @SrinidhiChennageri: "Can I make any changes in that, so that I can get the URL, everytime it hits the server through NETWORK-ACCESS" -- for any URLs you request directly, you know the URLs. For any URLs requested by libraries in your app... you might be able to create your own proxy server and have your process use that proxy server, but I cannot guarantee that everything that goes over HTTP will route through it. And that would *only* work for HTTP, not arbitrary protocols, let alone "other data service provider" (whatever that means).

Comment: @SrinidhiChennageri: If you root your device, you can arrange to proxy all Internet traffic, the way tools like Orbot do, but I do not know the details of how they accomplish this.

Comment: From the begining itself I was thinking to create a proxy server for my application and send all the HTTP requests through it. So that I can keep track of every URL request. But I just dont know how to implement this and from the other side I am lacking time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use open source proxy servers made in java for example jHTTPp2.It is having good implementation of proxy server logic.
All you need to do is just start the server from any android application and set proxy in your emulator or device to 127.0.0.1 and port as 8088(as by default the jHTTPp2 runs on that port).

You need to make some modifications to the proxy code as per Android requirements.

I hope this might be of some help to you.